# Assigning a C file handle to C++ file stream

Tags: c++, utf-8, stream, fopen

Can I open a file with C functions (`fopen`) and assign that handle to a C++ file stream (`fstream`...)?

Reason for asking: I want to handle UTF8 on windows but the `fstream` class has only a `const char*` ctor/open method. So I need to open it using the C API and then make a stream object use it.

It might even be possible with the boost stream library as it often allows specifying your own sinks/sources but I don't know where to start.

Clarification: I want to open a file with a path given as an UTF8 string. So the file open method must support UTF8 paths which `fstream` does not. The MSVC extension accepting a `const wchar_t*` does help, but MinGW does not provide these overloads. So I'd need to use `wfopen` on windows instead.

Comment: I may be missing something but `UTF-8` requires normal width `char*` buffers. Also the fstream open method only deals with the file name so it makes no difference what encoding the file contains. Can you be more specific about why opening files with fstream is not working?

Comment: Reading strings from an `fstream` depends on which locale is assigned to it.

Comment: The filename is UTF8. Added that above

Comment: Note: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397007/utf-8-names-with-boostfilestream-under-mingw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I open a file with C functions (`fopen`) and assign that handle to a C++ file stream (`fstream`...)?

Not directly, no.  But you can write (or find) a custom [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) derived class that handles I/O using `FILE*`, and then assign an instance of that class to a standard `std::istream` object.  See the implementation of [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) to help you, or GNU's `stdio_filebuf` class.

> I want to open a file with a path given as an UTF8 string. So the file open method must support UTF8 paths which `fstream` does not. The MSVC extension accepting a `const wchar_t*` does help, but MinGW does not provide these overloads. So I'd need to use `wfopen` on windows instead.

Most Unicode APIs on Windows do not support UTF-8, only UTF-16. Thus the `wchar_t` overloads in Visual C++ and other compatible compilers. Mingw simply does not support those extensions.  There are 3rd party solutions, though. Such as [Pathie](https://quintus.github.io/pathie-cpp/index.html) (see the `Pathie::ifstream` and `Pathie::ofstream` classes).

Comment: As added in the question: The filename is UTF8. Do you happen to know an implementation that works with that or if there is a boost component for this?

Comment: Thank you! The library boost:nowide is also helpful as it provides the `iofstream` classes. Pathie could probably replace all the boost::filesystem stuff but I'd rather complement them. Or do you have any comments/experience  with either?